Why is the registry key for turning off auto-complete in File Explorer's address bar not working anymore in Windows 11?
You once in Windows could turn off this auto-complete feature in the File Explorer's address bar, looking like this:

By modifying the registry with this key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete

And there setting a string named AutoSuggest to value No.
Yet this does not work anymore.
Is there another way to disable this behavior?
Note: In the auto-complete settings modal, certain options are removed, it looks like this:

Full version specification is: Windows 11 Professional, Version 10.0.26100 Build 26100.

@DrMoishePippik this question is about the File Explorer, not the obsolete Internet Explorer (which isn't even installed on my system)

Oops.. sorry, the settings Internet AutoComplete  for (file) Explore are under Content: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/119367-enable-disable-autosuggest-file-explorer-run-windows.html

@DrMoishePippik That doesn't work.  In this modal, the whole upper part of options are missing. See the image in the edit of the original question. Do you have Windows 11 and actually see those options? What build do you have, precisely?

Haven't moved to 11 -- using Win 10 & Linux, so the only advice I can give is based on that URL.
